# Fixed positioned element hide under another element and not clickable

Tags: html, css

I want a footer with fixed position at the bottom. 
The HTML code is

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) 
.cws_social_links-icon {
      display:block;
      vertical-align:middle;
      position:fixed;
      text-align:left;
      bottom:0px;
      right:20px;
      z-index:10000;
      height:56px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cws_social_links-icon  animated fadeIn">
      <a href="//facebook.com" class="icon_link"><i data-font-color="#ffffff" data-bg-color="#3b5998" class="cws_fa flaticon-facebook55 fa-lg custom_colors square kill_gradient" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(59, 89, 152); border-color: rgb(59, 89, 152);"></i></a>
      <a href="//twitter.com" class="icon_link"><i data-font-color="#ffffff" data-bg-color="#55acee" class="cws_fa flaticon-twitter1 fa-lg custom_colors square kill_gradient" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(85, 172, 238); border-color: rgb(85, 172, 238);"></i></a>
      <a href="//linkedin.com" class="icon_link"><i data-font-color="#ffffff" data-bg-color="#28A6EC" class="cws_fa fa fa-linkedin fa-lg custom_colors square kill_gradient" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(40, 166, 236); border-color: rgb(40, 166, 236);"></i></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
```

The problem is 'Fixed position elements' hides under the static element of container .

Comment: Please can you create a [MCVE]

Comment: I agree with @Pete. But adding some margin should sort you out. (I can only give a vague answer for a vague example)

Comment: The supplied css is not valid, and your html is a snippet of the code it would required to debug what is "hiding" under what. Please consider using http://jsfiddle.net to create an accurate representation of the issue you're facing